# NavigatorIOS problems

Tags: react-native

Hi I'm having some trouble using the NavigatorIOS in my app, it gives me the error:'undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push').
I tried to see some examples but I can't see the error, can someone help me? 
Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
import Menu from './Menu'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  NavigatorIOS,
  FadeInView,
  Text,
  View
 } from 'react-native';


class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.onForward = this.onForward.bind(this);
  }

  onForward(Menu){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component: Menu,
      title: "Menu",
      navigationBarHidden: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={styles.img}
          source={require('./img/scrittaNera.png')}
          onLoadStart={(e) => this.setState({loading: true})}
          />
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={() =>     this.onForward()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get Inspired</Text>
         </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the function to your Component in this case this can be done as follows:

```
<TouchableHighlight 
  style={styles.button} 
  onPress=this.onForward.bind(this)>
....
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Also you need to make sure your main component is wrapped inside a `<NavigatorIOS>` component. Such as:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { NavigatorIOS, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class NavigatorIOSApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        initialRoute={{
          component: MyScene,
          title: 'My Initial Scene',
        }}
        style={{flex: 1}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank's alot, now everything as it should!

Comment: I'm glad that was useful for you.

Comment: The program suddenly started to give an error that says: 

Element type is invalid: expected a string(for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. check the render method of 'NavigatorIOS'.

any clue on what to do?

Comment: Make sure you are exporting your module usually is one of main problems that that happens is because you are missing the export on the component used on the Navigator.